# CURL Error: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST

Tags: curl, terminal

I am trying to following CURL command in mac terminal:

```bash
curl --X POST \
  --url http://localhost:3000/api \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  --header 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  --header 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  --header 'postman-token: 6994926d-2406-b65e-d7e2-6a3622588c09' \
  --header 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  --header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' \
  --data '{"query":"mutation{\n  sendMessage(input:{toUserId:\"4789838293237760\",message:\"Hello, Are you there?\"})\n  {\n  id\n  message\n    modifiedOn\n    linkedUsers\n    {\n      id\n role\n firstName\n lastName \n   }\n    \n  }\n}","variables":null}' \
  -F file=@/Volumes/Drive \
  B/dev/zapi/uploads/IMG-20180207-WA0020.jpg
```

**Why am I getting the following error:**

> You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The problem with the CURL request command is you are using both `--data` (Post Data) and `-F` (Multiform Data).**

Thats is why it is giving error.

Here is the answer:

```bash
curl --X POST \
  --url http://localhost:3000/api \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  --header 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  --header 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  --header 'postman-token: 6994926d-2406-b65e-d7e2-6a3622588c09' \
  --header 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  --header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' \
  -F file=@/Volumes/Drive\ B/dev/zapi/uploads/IMG-20180207-WA0020.jpg \
  -F "query=mutation{\n  sendMessage(input:{toUserId:\"4789838293237760\",message:\"Hello, Are you there?\"})\n  {\n  id\n  message\n    modifiedOn\n    linkedUsers\n    {\n      id\n role\n firstName\n lastName \n   }\n    \n  }\n}" \
  -F "variables=null"
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to fix?